# Why Sequence.predit_proba() doesn't print classification probability

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have a x_train with 34 dimension, which are some stock technical indicator data. And y_train is label, which is binary(1,0) represent the stock is uptrend or downtrend. x_test is the stock technical indicator data thich I want to use to predict trend. Here is my code.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=34))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=50, verbose=0)
print(model.predict_proba(x_test, batch_size=50))
```

However I got this:

```
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 ...
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
```

How can I get a pair of proba about class '1' and class '0'?

Comment: These are not programming questions, I think you just haven't trained the model properly, and you are not aware that 0.0 is also a probability.

Comment: however it should be a two-dimension but this is a one-dimension

Comment: The shape is (samples, 1), which is 2D.

Comment: I think it should has a probability of class '1' and a probability of class '2'

Comment: No, that is with a softmax, a sigmoid activation gives you a single scalar, close to zero means class 1, and close to one means class 2.

Comment: I change the activation of output layer to softmax. predict_proba() still output a single column......